Why Task Scheduler is not running
I have a task that runs a java application through command prompt
It is supposed to run every minute
at every minute the Next Run Time changes to the next minute but the Last Run Time stays the same and task never runs unless I go and hit the Run button

Here are more details of the task





You could "Enable All Tasks History" (in the Actions pane on the right) to see if anything useful is reported in the History tab.
